# What is the name of a button control in DX.10.2?

Tags: devexpress

What is the name of a button control in DX.10.2?

cannot find a simple button.

am using vs10, silverlight..

thanku

Answer (score 2):

Please open VS with admin permission,
if the above thing is not working follow this

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/KA18574.aspx

1. Download the ToolboxAnalyzer archive and extract it to your local drive.
2. Run the ToolboxAnalyzer application.
3. Select the Visual Studio version that is having a toolbox issue.
4. Click the "Test Toolbox and attempt to repair it" button.
5. Follow the instructions provided by the application.
6. If the application closes unexpectedly or crashes with an error, please collect all files from the "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\DX Toolbox Analyzer" folder, create a new ticket regarding this problem, and attach logs to your message.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is `ButtonEdit`. Add the `Editors .dll` and have a look.

Comment: its there, but it not a button

Comment: You use the ButtonEdit:
'<dxe:ButtonEdit 
                    x:Name="editor3"
                    ShowText="False"
                    AllowDefaultButton="False"
                >
                        <dxe:ButtonInfo x:Name="refresh" GlyphKind="Refresh" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Refresh"/>
                    </dxe:ButtonEdit>'

Answer (score 1):

We do not provide a SimpleButton for SL/WFF platforms.  Drop the standard Button onto the form and it will be skinned by our ThemeManager. For more details, please refer to [DevExpress Silverlight Themes](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/CustomDocument4941)